# Plotting best curved line in Mathematica

Tags: plot, graph, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I would ask please for your kind assistance. I am currently trying to plot the best curve (it may be exponential, logarithmic, hyperbolic, etc) for a set of points which I generate. Thus far I have been using this type of code:

```
Show[ListPlot[
  L, {PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 50}}, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Tiny]}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness -> Tiny, FontSize -> 12], 
   AspectRatio -> 0.8, GridLines -> Automatic, Joined -> {False}, 
   TicksStyle -> Directive[1]}]]
```

I am aware that if I change the Joined -> to "True" I would get a line joining the points, however I wish to have the best curve not a line joining the points.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried looking at the mathematica docs? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do that in *Mathematica*. For example, you can use the [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) function or [`ListInterpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html). Also as [agentp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542323/plotting-best-curved-line-in-mathematica#comment62621584_37542323) mentioned, you can use model fitting functions such as [`LinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html), [`GeneralizedLinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneralizedLinearModelFit.html) or [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html).

Refer to the linked documentations for more info.

Comment: Thanks very much yes. Used the Interpolation function and worked like a charm